# How to use React with Python and keep both frontend and backend separate?

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, flask-login, rauth

I am using React as `frontend` and  Python & Flask as my `backend` with `Rauth` as `OAuth2` for Facebook login and storing details of every user in db and using `flask_login` as protection. Those information are Sports, Education, Phone number and other things.

What I am doing is after user gets logged in I am trying to `fetch` his details from react app. But I am getting error user not logged in while on browser if I open that API I can see the `json`.

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.select().where(User.id == id).first()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return redirect(WEB_URL)


@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(WEB_URL)


@app.route('/me')
@login_required  # After removing decorator still I am not getting
def me():
    return jsonify({'email': current_user.email}), 200



@app.route('/authorize/<provider>')
def oauth_authorize(provider):
    if not current_user.is_anonymous:
        return redirect(WEB_URL)
    oauth = OAuthSignIn.get_provider(provider)
    return oauth.authorize()


@app.route('/callback/<provider>')
def oauth_callback(provider):
    if not current_user.is_anonymous:
        return redirect(WEB_URL)
    oauth = OAuthSignIn.get_provider(provider)
    social_id, username, email = oauth.callback()
    if social_id is None:
        return redirect(WEB_URL)
    user = User.select().where(User.social_id == social_id).first()
    if not user:
        user = User(social_id=social_id, nickname=username, email=email)
        user.save()
    login_user(user, True)
    return redirect(WEB_URL)
```

So from fronend I am calling `/authorize/<provider>` which then redirects to `/callback/<provider>` and logs user in.

Now When I am opening `/me` on browser it works fine returns required `json` or redirects me to homepage.

But when I am trying to fetch the api from frontend or Postman either I am getting user not found (if I remove the decorator `login_required`) or returning the whole homepage.

I am fetching like this:

```
componentWillMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/me').then(function(response) {
      const contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
      if(contentType && contentType.includes("application/json")) {
        return response.json();
      }
    }).then(function(json) {
        debugger
        const self = this;
        if (json) self.serState({ loggedIn: true });     
    }).catch(function(error) { console.log(error); });
  }
```

My `frontend` is running on `http://localhost:3000/`

**Got the Answer**
Backend add this line after importing flask_cors

```
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
```

And Fetch using

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/me', {
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'include'
    })
```

Comment: When you send the request from Postman, are you sending the session cookie? That's how Flask-Login on the server recognizes who you are.

Comment: @Miguel No I am not sending session cookie. I just want to fetch user details  from `/me` after he log in via FB. So I am doing a fetch request . I have updated question how I am fetching

Comment: How is the server going to know who you are if you don't send the session cookie?

Comment: @Miguel thanks for responding I got the answer. Is it just safe to communicate with backend like above I have answered.

Answer (score 0):

Install flask restful
https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Use rxjs to grab data from the api using a "service"